# Correct writing of 酉

Tags: writing, handwriting

Wenlin dictionary describes the writing of 酉 by a third stroke as a  héngzhé  and not a ㇆ héngzhégōu.
When i look at [https://www.zdic.net/hans/酉](https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E9%85%89)   it is more a ㇆ héngzhégōu.
When i look at https://www.archchinese.com/chinese_english_dictionary.html?find=%E9%85%89  it looks like Wenlin writing.
Does this character built with 囗 wéi or 口 kǒu ? 西 is described by Wenlin as a component of 酉, and 西 is built with 囗.
Then it should by written with the ㇆ héngzhégōu stroke (and both Wenlin and archchinese would be wrong ? ).

Comment: `Does this character built with 囗 wéi or 口 kǒu ? 西 is described by Wenlin as a component of 酉, and 西 is built with 囗.` "Component" in this situation should only be interpreted as a collection of strokes making a shape; do not attach a pronunciation like `囗 wéi or 口 kǒu`, that implies that the characters 酉 or 西 is made up of `囗 wéi or 口 kǒu`, which is **absolutely incorrect**.

Comment: Yes, there is something incorrect, that's why i ask here.  西  is part of the indecomposable characters, ok. But graphically, to remember in an easier way, it contains at the end of writing  囗 wéi or 口 kǒu. 酉 is also part of the indecomposable characters ( GF 0013-2009  on http://www.myyxzj.com/article/032fdeee-77aa-422d-bd3a-86c4c9633766.shtml )  but we can consider that it is made of 西 in which is added graphically (when writing is done) an horizontal stroke.  Then is it  héngzhé or ㇆ héngzhégōu ?  the third stroke in 酉 ?

Answer (score 3):

**Stroke Sequence -**

[image]

[image]
Kangxi Radical #164 (composition 西一)

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%85%89

[image]Radical 146

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%A5%BF

**- Radical 31 囗+2 (composition 儿囗)**

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%F0%A0%81%A4

[image]Radical 31 (composition 冂一)

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%9B%97

[image]Radical 13 (composition丨)

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%86%82

[image]Radical 5

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%F0%A0%83%8C

Comment: La composition " composition ⿴西一 " n'est pas correcte sur ce site : dans  酉  一 n'est pas tracé après l'autre composant. De plus  酉 est indécomposable, ce qui n'empêche pas qu'il faut bien le tracer, avec les strokes correctes et l'ordre correct ! ma question porte sur la nature de 3 ème trait : héngzhé ou héng zhégōu ?  le site en.wiktionary semble opter pour le deuxième, comme zdic.net  :-)

Comment: De plus le site https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/  envoie vers 囗  wéi

Comment: @faure English seems to be the main language of the forum, please avoid needing others to translate your writing. You can find a textbook that teaches elementary Chinese handwriting to verify your case.

Comment: The composition " ⿴ 西 一" is not correct on this site: in 酉 一 is not drawn after the other component. Moreover 酉 is indecomposable, which does not prevent it from having to be traced well, with the correct strokes and the correct order! my question concerns the nature of the 3rd trait: héngzhé or héngzhégōu? the en.wiktionary site seems to opt for the second, like zdic.net

Comment: Thanks, i translated...   "You can find a textbook that teaches elementary Chinese handwriting to verify your case. " feel free to share such a textbook :-)   where i can find CORRECT  answers !

Comment: @faure I think you're misunderstanding what `⿴西一` means. The [ideographic description characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideographic_Description_Characters_\(Unicode_block\)) are a way of describing a character based on other Unicode-encoded characters *treated as shapes*. It does not say anything about linguistically-relevant character components, or that you write 西 before 一 in terms of stroke order to build up 酉.

Comment: @faure Found one from ebay. You should also ask the person who taught you Chinese. https://www.ebay.com/itm/363151118528?chn=ps&_trkparms=ispr%3D1&amdata=enc%3A1x_YJivkBSA2RAlOZ_RbWaQ91&norover=1&mkevt=1&mkrid=711-213727-13078-0&mkcid=2&itemid=363151118528&targetid=4581046488761455&device=c&mktype=&googleloc=&poi=&campaignid=418640322&mkgroupid=1239149842233245&rlsatarget=pla-4581046488761455&abcId=9300602&merchantid=51291&msclkid=d6c4e557c86b16e7585f846b78cf04d5

Comment: @faure Also recommend is "the basic strokes of Chinese writing" (link 1) and "the Chines radicals" (link 2). https://www.saporedicina.com/english/chinese-radicals/ https://hsk.academy/en/learn/the-chinese-radicals

Answer (score 3):

In reality there is no difference. Usually, after you write , you naturally lift the pen to write the next stroke, and it will naturally form a 勾, making it ㇆. They are more like stylistic choices you can freely make. It's like how you write the letter a: it does not matter.
[image]

Different fonts treat this differently.

Governments try to make standards. In real life, people don't care. You needn't care either, unless you are preparing for an exam specific on strokes (I'm not aware that such exams exist), or you have academic interests in strokes. Normal exams won't make you lose points for such minor stylistic aspects.

Current standards of each region:

ROC:

[image]

source: [中華民國教育部 常用國字標準字體筆順學習網](https://stroke-order.learningweb.moe.edu.tw/charactersQueryResult.do?words=%E9%85%89&lang=zh_TW&csrfPreventionSalt=null)

PRC:

[image]

source: [中华人民共和国教育部国家语言文字工作委员会 通用规范汉字笔顺规范(pdf)](http://www.moe.gov.cn/jyb_sjzl/ziliao/A19/202103/W020210318300204215237.pdf) (This file does not even use 楷体, which should usually be used for handwriting.)

The next picture is from https://www.hanzi5.com/bishun/9149.html, a site for learners of simplified Chinese. Notice the subtle stroke which is kind of like in the middle of  and ㇆.

[image]